# Looking for a smooth way to provide completion time in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a cell I4 which stores Date and cell I5 which stores time.
Based on values in those cells is there a way to provide a Completion Time through either VBA or formula in another cell G6 ?

Completion time is 4 hours.

The problem I'm facing is if completion time is exceeding 17:00 then the stopwatch should be stopped and resume counting from 9:00 following day:

Example

I4 = 09/03/2022
I5 = 15:15
G6 - Completion Time should equal to 11:15 10/03/2022

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the date is formatted as a date and the time as time then you can add 4h to the time and add the date and time together. Or you can add them then add 4h...

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike, however that doesn't solve my problem when time exceeds 17:00

Comment: Oh, so 3:15 is actually 15:15 not 03:15AM... Now that becomes clearer. Then add an if() to control the result.

Comment: Yes it's 15:15. Apologies I have amended the explanation. What If statement are we able to use here please ?

Comment: Well, you can start with something like IF(I5>=13:00,do_this,Or_do_that)

Comment: OK so without the exception the formula would look like =I5+4/24  with if statement I'm not sure what should go to true part  =IF(I5>=17:00, do_this, I5+4/24

Comment: So your condition of the end time is now 17:00 + 4hours?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion here. No the condition is to add whatever remaining time is left after cut off (17:00)  to the next day starting from 9:00 so above example  would be 11:15 10/03/2022. If there is no cut off then I presume it would be simply I5+4/24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can work with this:

[image]

All the cells are formatted as time.

Answer (score 1):

A neat way of doing this could potentially be using `REDUCE()`:

[image]

Formula in `K4`:

```
=REDUCE(I$4+I$5,SEQUENCE(I7*1440,,,0)/1440,LAMBDA(a,b,IF((a+b)>(INT(a)+TIME(17,,)),a+TIME(16,1,),a+b)))
```

As per the screenshot you can see this will now work for any completion time you have in the `[h]:mm` format.