# Calculating regular hours and night hours between time and dates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have got a problem in where i try to make an excel spreadsheet to keep track of my wage and that i am paid the correct amount.

I recieve different rates depending on the time of day. I get X during the day and Y during the night which is from 23:00 (11PM) Which means if i show up to work at 16:00 (4PM) and leave at 1:15 (01:15AM) i should get 7 hours at X rate and 2.25 hours at Y rate.

However i can't seem to figure out how to format my cells in excel so that they take and Check in time and a check out time. And then figure out how many regular hours and how many night hours are in it.

[**Snip of data sample**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sk7g.png)

Comment: Calculate total hours then workk out day hours and difference must be night hours. remember to subtract breaks and meal hours... If all cells are formatted time then should be fine, also make sure you work out after midnight.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71407846/4961700

Comment: "Day" hours can be calculated by 2300 minus time-in (if <2300), then "Night" hours are total hours minus "Day" hours.  As such, you may want a column for "total hours" to make a few simple formulae for calculating (and makes checking a bit simpler).