# Comparing the number of hours between two dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code:

```
Sub LBDuration()

    Dim startDateTime, endDateTime As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    RowCount = Sheets("passengers").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To RowCount
        startDateTime = Sheets("passengers").Range("F" & i).Value
        endDateTime = Now()
        Sheets("passengers").Range("G" & i).Value = Format((endDateTime - startDateTime), "hh:mm")
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

For example the cell will display

```
21/05/2022 23:59
```

But obviously, hours only go to 24 and it just resets... however can I get it to go further than this?

Because if the difference is over 24 hours? or even is there a way to show it like:

```
1 day & 23 hours
```

Comment: Format it `"[hh]:mm"`

Comment: You can calculate the time across midnight like so : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71408653/4961700